# Android listselection color for different version

Tags: android, select

In kit kat its gray, in ice cream sandwich its light blue. may i know whats the color in jelly bean 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3? And how can I change selection color over entire app? I dont wanna go one by one on each listview and touch click put selection color.

In ginerbread my main problem occurs, because gingerbread and groyo somehow selection color on list is yellow..on actionitem is light blue.
I am using actionbarsherlock in my app.

> ```
>   <ExpandableListView
>             android:id="@+id/lvExp"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         />
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article(http://android-journey.blogspot.in/2009/12/android-selectors.html) on how to use selectors with lists.

Instead of setting it to be the android:background of the ListView, I believe you want to set android:listSelector as shown below:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dip"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

list_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: if i put there @color/light_gray it does errors in gingerbread? it starts highlighting whole table... altho i have indentified singlechoice.

Comment: dont go with color go with @drawable/list_selector make one selector and pass it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 android:divider="#00000000"
 android:fadingEdge="none"
 android:listSelector="@drawable/row_selector"
```

code of row_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="1.0dip" android:color="@color/text" />
</shape>
```

Code of color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="text">#ff74767a</color>
</resources>
```